# Getting the sum of two variables on Stata with missing values

Tags: stata

How do I `generate` a new variable which gives me the sum of two variables (`msf_n_4weeks` and `msm_n_4weeks`) but only assigns a missing value if BOTH of the values for the variables is missing. The variables have missing values and also 0 as a value. I used the below code and it assigned the value `0` to those where the sum is 0 but also to those where both variables have missing values.

```
egen m_n_4weeks = rowtotal(msf_n_4weeks msm_n_4weeks)
```

Instead, I want to get something like this:

```
msf_n_4weeks  msm_n_4weeks  m_n_4weeks
5             3             8                  
0             2             2                     
12            0             12                    
6             .             6                
.             5             5                
.             .             .
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is very close to the solution: see `rowtotal()` in the `egen` [help](https://www.stata.com/manuals/degen.pdf) file.

```
egen m_n_4weeks = rowtotal(msf_n_4weeks msm_n_4weeks), missing
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clear 
input msf_n_4weeks  msm_n_4weeks  m_n_4weeks
5             3             8                  
0             2             2                     
12            0             12                    
6             .             6                
.             5             5                
.             .             .     
end 

local a msf_n_4weeks 
local b msm_n_4weeks 
gen wanted = cond(missing(`a') & missing(`b'), . , cond(missing(`b'), 0, `b') + cond(missing(`a'), 0, `a'))
```

is another way to do it.